# Where is << defined for STDOUT?

Tags: ruby

I'm currently reading a book that says `STDOUT` is a constant. My question is what kind of object is it?

When I say, for example, `[1,2] << 3`, I know `<<` is defined in the `Array` class.

When I put code like this:

```
STDOUT << "string" << "\n"
```

What is the definition of `<<` on the `STDOUT` constant?

Answer (score 1):

`<<` is usually implemented as *append*. For arrays, `<<` means append an element at the end of the array, for strings, `<<` means append the given object to the end of the string, etc.

[`IO#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-i-3C-3C) is similar, writing the given object to an IO stream, just like `std::stdout << "hello" << std::endl;` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a slightly more complex question than you think (or maybe not) ;)

A constant is something where the value doesn't change... in this case - we are constantly pointing at an instance of class `IO` (in this case the one that goes to the 'standard output").

that instance doesn't change - ie we're not assigning some new `IO` to it...

what we are doing is calling the `<<` method on it. which in this case lets you pass a bunch of strings to it... and then it outputs the strings 
to the standard output.

Answer (score 0):

Definition of `<<` on `stdout` can be found [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-3C-3C).

```
VALUE rb_io_addstr(VALUE io, VALUE str)
{
    rb_io_write(io, str);
    return io;
}
```

Yes, `STDOUT` is an constant in Ruby, this CAN be changed, but a warning will be issued. so Ideally it should not be changed.

`STDOUT = $stderr 
(irb):1: warning: al#=> #<IO:<STDERR>>constant STDOUT >> STDOUT #=> #<IO:<STDERR>>`

When you are doing `<<` on `STDOUT`, you are calling a function `<<` defined on `STDOUT`, Don't confuse with this that you are changing the value of `STDOUT`, you are basically appending in output stream.

Comment: How do *"you can't redefine it"* and *"which CAN be changed"* fit together?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, `STDOUT` is a constant, and it is an instance of the class `IO`, which is a part of the Ruby standard library. `IO` objects are used to wrap streams that let you read from and write to different files. (On UNIX systems, all devices are treated as files.) The default input (`STDIN`) is the keyboard, and the default output (`STDOUT`) is the terminal.

The `IO` class is just a regular Ruby class, and it's methods, including `<<` are defined in the [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html). However, the documentation on `<<` is a bit sparse, and leaves out any lower level details:

> **ios << obj → ios**
>
> String Output---Writes obj to ios. obj will be converted to a string using to_s.

There are also a set of globals, `$stdin` and `$stdout`, that correspond to the constants. By default, these will point to their respective constant, but can be changed, whereas the constants will always point to the default stream `IO` objects.